# Good Neo4J optimization settings

Tags: performance, jvm, neo4j

We are looking to load and analyze 100 million node Node4J graph on a 16 core, 48 GB ram machine.

We are doing this to do basic relational-vs-graph performance analysis.

We are looking into some set of recommended, default Neo4J settings 
(JVM, any Neo4J specific on caching, etc.) for the graph of this size and on a machine of specified hardware profile.

Please advise,
Edmon

Comment: How many relationships and properties do you want to import?

Comment: What kind of disk do you have? Spinning or SSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For loading use the [Neo4j Batch inserter](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/batchinsert.html) with a large heap (40G, mmio is part of the heap there). This is an [example project](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) on how to read csv files.

For the analysis go with the enterprise edition and use the [GCR cache](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/embedded-configuration.html). You might want to have between 20-30G heap the rest of the memory for mmio.

Make sure to warm up the caches before you do the comparison. E.g. by iterating over `GlobalGraphOperations.at(gdb).getAllNodes() | getAllRelationships()`.

To measure the maximum performance use the embedded database and the Neo4j Core API from java. What are the use-cases you're looking at?